# Preprocessor directive in middle of c++ function?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
void VoxelTerrain::set_stream(Ref<VoxelStream> p_stream) {
    if (p_stream == _stream) {
        return;
    }

    _stream = p_stream;

#ifdef TOOLS_ENABLED
    if (_stream.is_valid()) {
        if (Engine::get_singleton()->is_editor_hint()) {
            Ref<Script> script = _stream->get_script();
            if (script.is_valid()) {
                // Safety check. It's too easy to break threads by making a script reload.
                // You can turn it back on, but be careful.
                _run_stream_in_editor = false;
                _change_notify();
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    _on_stream_params_changed();
}
```

When does the #ifdef execute in the above function? I thought # indicated a preprocessor directive which executed before actual code. And yet in this code the preprocessor stuff seems to reference an actual object that could only be instantiated after compilation and execution?

Comment: If `TOOLS_ENABLED` is __not__ defined then it's as if the section of code ( `#ifdef` to `#endif` ) does not exist.

Comment: The term you're looking for is conditional compilation.

Comment: I have been guilty of code that looks sort-of like `int array[] = { #include "data.csv" };`

Comment: The preprocessor does not care about the content. In this case compilation steps that come later either see the code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` or they don't, depending on whether the preprocessor knows about a definition of a preprocessor symbol TOOLS_ENABLED or not. You could even go more crazy with this and the compiler wouldn't complain `void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; #ifdef BAR } void bar() {std::cout << "bar\n"; #endif }` (line breaks need to be added of course)

Comment: Fabian's point about the preprocessor not caring becomes very important later when you start playing with macros. A `#define IDENTIFIER replacement` results in utterly stupid text substitution. Everywhere `IDENTIFIER` is found it is replaced with `replacement` no matter how illogical, insane, or downright stupid it would be to make the substitution. Be very careful with macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does the #ifdef execute in the above function?

It is executed before "the compiler" sees the code.  If the preprocessor knows what the `TOOLS_ENABLED` symbol is, then the preprocessor continues to pass this code to the compiler.

If the preprocessor does not know what `TOOLS_ENABLED` is, then it will skip this chunk of code, and not pass that code to the compiler.

Its a common trick, usually to allow "debug" builds to do a bunch of additional validation to affirm that no bug has occured, but to eliminate all this slow doublechecking from "release" builds so that they run super fast.